# kendo UI mobile ListView hang after opening external link on native browser

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, kendo-ui

In a Kendo UI Mobile ListView, a script to open an external link by native browser is called when a link is clicked.

The PhoneGap script is as follow:
On Android:
navigator.app.loadUrl(link,  { openExternal:true } );
On iOS:
window.open(link, '_system');

The link can be opened on the corresponding native browser.

However, when the user switch back to the app from the native browser, some problems happen.

On Android, the screen hung on the original view, when the back button is pressed again, the screen is un-freezed and can be refreshed.

On iOS, however, the screen is also hung on the original view. When tapped on the screen, the complete view (with the layout) is moved. There is no way to un-freeze this screen.

How to fix this so that the screen can be un-frezzed after switching back from the native browser to the app?

Thank you very much for your help.

Updated 1:

I changed the original  tag to a  tag, everythings work now. But I am still curious to see if it is certain kind of bugs for Kendo UI Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

There is a serious problem with Kendo Mobile hanging the page completely, making the app totally unresponsive to touch/mouse. The offending CSS is in Loader.transition() which does `this.container.css("pointer-events", "none")` which is equivalent to:

```
document.body.style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

Ouch - that is ugly. Plus in _attachCapture there is offensive JavaScript for all mouse and touch events that does:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Fatal if using an app with an embedded full page WebView/UIWebView (requiring app to be closed and restarted).

Hangs can happen if:

- You have an exception in your code (even in unobvious places),
- You mistype a transition (no exception, just hangs),
- A user's browser doesn't fire the transitionEnd event properly for some reason (This was repeatable for one user's up-to-date Chrome browser.
- There is a failure mode in the Interaction between page transitions and Loader (depending on timing, couldn't repeat),
- Multiple other causes

Note that there is a comment in Kendo that says: "This should be cleaned up at some point (widget by widget), and refactored to widgets not relying on the complete callback if no transition occurs.", so clearly Telerik know there is a problem.

You can use the following code during development to at least warn when Kendo Mobile has crapped itself:

```
var transitionTimer;
kendo.mobile.ui.Loader.prototype.wasTransition = kendo.mobile.ui.Loader.prototype.transition;
kendo.mobile.ui.Loader.prototype.transition = function() {
    transitionTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('Kendo has hung the page');
    }, 10000);
    this.wasTransition.apply(this, arguments);
}
kendo.mobile.ui.Loader.prototype.wasTransitionDone = kendo.mobile.ui.Loader.prototype.transitionDone;
kendo.mobile.ui.Loader.prototype.transitionDone = function() {
    clearTimeout(transitionTimer);
    this.wasTransitionDone.apply(this, arguments);
}
```